# PHP sorting issue, arsort vs asort + array_reverse

Tags: php, sorting

I was recently working on one of the project euler problem sets and came across this strange issue. I've solved the problem correctly with the first solution, but I don't know why the other version does not work as expected.

Here is the code that works:

```
asort($card_count, SORT_NUMERIC);
$card_count = array_reverse($card_count, true);
```

And here is the code that does not:

```
arsort($card_count, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

This is the only line i change and it makes a huge difference in the end result. Any ideas whats up with this?

Comment: How are you reading the array later on -- what indexes are you using?

Comment: Both of those are the same for me: http://codepad.org/80bWvlTv

Comment: Its a poker solution, so basically it is mapping the card value in the key (such as '2' or 'A', or 'J') to how many times it appeared in the input, so it may look like this ['A' => 2, '8' => 2, '4' => 1] to represent two aces, two eights's and one four. I rely on the fact that the highest amounts should be at the front and lower amounts at the back. I can post a full code solution if necessary, just didnt want to give away the answer as i know its against PE policy.

Comment: So you're saying this is homework.

Comment: Lawl, no, as I stated in the question, its a project euler problem which I have already solved...

Comment: I have updated the question to include the solution to the problem which works, by modifying that as stated it produces 404 winning hands instead of the expected value.

Comment: A better way of showing the code would be to produce a very simple demonstration of the problem. A short PHP snippet, defining an input array that works in one case but not in the other, and showing how the two cases differ. This would make it easier for us to focus on the problem, and also avoid you having to break the terms of PE.

Comment: Can you give us `var_dump($card_count)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue arises with sorting equal values in the array. Take the array:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 1,
    'd' => 1
);
```

Calling `asort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC)` on this array will **reverse the array**. Hence, the lines of code:

```
asort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
$arr = array_reverse($arr, true);
```

will put the array back in the **original order**.

So, adding in one value that's higher with change the array as such:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 1,
    'c' => 2,
    'd' => 1
);

asort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
$arr = array_reverse($arr, true);
```

will yeild:

```
Array
(
    [c] => 2
    [a] => 1
    [b] => 1
    [d] => 1
)
```

while

```
arsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

will yeild:

```
Array
(
    [c] => 2
    [d] => 1
    [b] => 1
    [a] => 1
)
```

Hopefully this sheds some light on the issue ...